# anova in R, summary meaning

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, anova

Does anyone knows what "Df", "Sum Sq", "Mean Sq", "F value", and "Pr(>F)" stands for when we print a summary of an aov() output?  I know it gives information about how groups are linked together but, does Mean Sq is the mean of the values from source 1 or from source 2? Or is it the difference between those 2? Or is it something else? I get what is the Sum Sq, mean Sq, F value, etc for a single group of data but what does it means when we compare two groups?

Here's an example of a summary.aov() for data representing the weightgain for beef/cereal(source) and high/low(type):
[image]

Comment: This might be better suited for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You compare two Sources. `SumSq` is based on their sample means and expresses how different they are;`SumSq/DF` in each row gives `MeanSq`. `F(Source) `= `MeanSq(Source)/MeanSq(Resid)` and similarly for `F(Type)` and `F(Source:Type)` Each P-value `Pr(>F)` tests hypothesis on a row of the table. Signif at 5% level if P-value < 0.05 (as for Type). In R, where `pf` is CDF of an F-distn, code `1 - pf(5.812,1,36)` returns P-value $0.02114809$ hence the `*` in the right margin denoting signif at 5% level.
.